# Azure Deployment Script fails with AuthenticationFailed

Tags: azure, azure-bicep

We have a fairly simple deployment script to add a delay:

```
resource  awaitscript  'Microsoft.Resources/deploymentScripts@2020-10-01' = {
  name: 'await-${appName}'
  location: location
  kind: 'AzurePowerShell'
  properties: {
    azPowerShellVersion: '9.7'
    scriptContent: 'Start-Sleep -Seconds 150'
    timeout: 'PT1H'
    retentionInterval: 'PT1H'
  }
  dependsOn: [appServicePlan]
}
```

It has been working for months however lately we have been seeing a lot of AuthenticationFailed-errors:

```
Server failed to authenticate the request. Make sure the value of Authorization header is formed correctly including the signature.
RequestId:3fefb479-b01a-00a1-40c4-f66f2e000000
Time:2023-10-04T13:12:59.8885812Z
Status: 403 (Server failed to authenticate the request. Make sure the value of Authorization header is formed correctly including the signature.)
ErrorCode: AuthenticationFailed

Additional Information:
AuthenticationErrorDetail: The MAC signature found in the HTTP request 'Nk9Ntma3CIMCxbWfd7xbeFAVTEIo7FAJDS3wL+xVNiI=' is not the same as any computed signature. Server used following string to sign: 'PUT
```

It seems to be out of scope of what we are doing - is this a known error and is there anything we can do about it? It appears to be failing when allocating resources for executing the deployment script. It is sporadic and sometimes it does work on retries.

Comment: Have you made any changes in your ARM authorization header? @Matt Immer

Comment: Are you executing the code from Azure CLI? If yes, have you updated the CLI version to the latest. @Matt Immer

Comment: We are also facing the same issue when trying to create a Deployment Script using ARM templates. We have also updated the AzureCli version to 2.52.0 still the issue persists.

Comment: @Jahnavi no changes to auth as far as I'm aware! And it does work sporadically. We are using DevOps pipelines with hosted agents so the version that is being used is 2.52.0

Comment: This might be a temporary happening because of the invalid tokens. Have you checked the tokens generated are up to date and not expired. @MattImmer

Comment: Can you check if [this](https://www.appsloveworld.com/azure/50/the-mac-signature-found-in-the-http-request-39-39-is-not-the-same-as-any-co) works. @MattImmer

Comment: @Jahnavi as far as I understand, because I'm not specifying any storage account in my configuration, the SA and a container will automatically be created and deleted. So the SA you are asking me to check against is already deleted by then? Or am I misunderstanding? :)

Comment: Are you using any storage account in your code? @MattImmer

Comment: We are allocating other storage accounts in the Bicep but I would be surprised if that affects the deployment-script. The Bicep snippet I have as an example is 100% a copy of what is failing for us. @Jahnavi

Comment: That should not effect the current deployment script. Can you clear the cache in CLI and try again with the same script? @MattImmer

Comment: And also check the time drift between the client and the server. It can also lead to the authentication signature mismatch. @MattImmer

Comment: @Jahnavi I don't see how I would go about doing that when I'm using Azure-managed build agents unfortunately. I feel there is a general issue if the time on the build agent is off.

Comment: Can you try running the bicep code in Azure bash once? Is it possible for you? @MattImmer

Comment: I tried a few times and it actually appears to be working just fine - Though it is also a newer version of az cli (2.53.0) @Jahnavi

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/255529/discussion-between-jahnavi-and-matt-immer).

Comment: Having the exact same problem. Started a couple days ago. The hosted agent we're using is ubuntu-latest, and based on [this information](https://github.com/actions/runner-images/blob/main/images/linux/Ubuntu2204-Readme.md), it already has AZ CLI v2.53.0.

Comment: +1. We have the same issue. Deployments were working fine for almost a year and this error showed up a few days ago without any changes to the script.

Answer (score 3):

This is an intermittent issue in Azure, probably akin to an outage, beginning roughly around mid day US eastern time on 10/2/23, and ongoing to the time of this comment. Since we constantly use deployment scripts as part of our CICD, we have a good view of the scope. We've seen it every hour since it began.

It appears to be an issue with the Azure Container Instance authenticating with something, possibly the associated storage account. The issue originally occurred most frequently when using the `supportingScriptUris` property of a deployment script. Moving all of our deployment scripts to manually download assets the script needs has reduced the rate of error. However in the past few hours we've seen errors increase whether or not `supportingScriptUris` is used. As well, it happens in every region we've tried it across the US.

There are still issues when bringing your own storage, but the error surfaces as an "invalid key."

Unfortunately the multiple avenues of support we've tried have not acknowledged the issue or offered a timeframe for resolution or workaround.

Comment: In the OP example (as in the ones I'm having trouble with) the whole script is inline and there's nothing to download, but perhaps the deploymentScripts resource itself is trying to write the script to disk before running it. I think there's a general slowdown in newly created things getting roles/access in Azure.

Comment: yea, we are also seeing it without using the supportingScriptUris, but we see it more frequently when using it. ill amend my answer to note this. but when using the bring-your-own-storage approach with deployment scripts, we see an invalid key error. So my gut leans towards a key problem, not role.

Comment: Received an update from the Azure Support team that this has been resolved now. I have also verified all my ARM templates are working fine now.

Comment: Turned deployment scripts back on in our deployments and first attempt succeeded. Looks like the issue may be resolved.

Comment: @AnuragRawat we thought it was resolved today too, but we've just started seeing it again this hour. did they say what it was or point to any public announcement? our support ticket won't respond

Comment: @harlam357 have you seen it return recently?

Comment: @NickSpag Azure Support didn't respond to what was the exact issue, they told us that the issue had been mitigated and from that moment we haven't encountered the issue till now. Are you still facing the issue?

Comment: @AnuragRawat we're seeing it a lot less, but Azure did finally add it to their service health page as a global outage. So it looks like it could still potentially be ongoing.

Comment: @NickSpag, I have not seen the issue again. Deployments are flowing fine for us.